# SQL insert certain data from one table to another

Tags: mysql

I am trying to move data from `users` table to `mailing` table with this code

```
INSERT INTO `mailing_lists` (user_id, email)
SELECT id, email FROM `users`;
```

This has moved data (not all of them!) but also returned this error

> Static analysis:
>
> 1 errors were found during analysis.
>
> Missing expression. (near "ON" at position 25)
> SQL query: Edit Edit
>
> SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = ON;
>
> MySQL said: Documentation
>
> ## 2006 - MySQL server has gone away

**Question**

What I did wrong and what's the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 0;

INSERT INTO `mailing_lists` (user_id, email)
SELECT id, email FROM `users`;

SET FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS = 1;
```